# Not geting token Google Oauth

Tags: google-oauth, codeigniter-4

I'm trying to use google API for login but for some reason both `$_GET["code"]` and `$this->request->getVar('code')` are empty and I can't fetch my token because of it. I have tried `$_GET["code"]` instead of `$this->request->getVar('code')` but nothing is working:

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBKbi.png) [second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opgMO.png)

I was following this video tutorial: [click here](https://youtu.be/VDBJMS4zl8I)

```php
public function signup_with_gmail() {
   
    require_once APPPATH.'Libraries\vendor\autoload.php';
    $google_client = new \Google_Client();
    //$google_client->setApplicationName("pharma");
    $google_client->setClientId('clientID');
    $google_client->setClientSecret('SECRET');
    $google_client->setRedirectUri('http://localhost/pharma/User/sign_in');
    $google_client->addScope('email');
    $google_client->addScope('profile');
    
    print_r($this->request->getVar('code') === NULL);
    print_r($_GET['code']);
    if ($this->request->getVar('code') != NULL) {
        $token = $google_client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($this->request->getVar('code'));
        if(!$token['error']){
            $google_client->setAccessToken($token['access_token']);
            $session->set('access_token', $token['access_token']);
            //now get profile data create another object
            $google_service = new \Google_Service_Oauth2($google_client);
            $data = $google_service->userinfo->get();
            print_r($data);
        }
    }
    print_r($data);
}
```

Comment: I have check on github stack over flow but all were related to token refresh but what my problem is that $_GET['code'] or $this->request->getVar('code') should return something from google but its empty

Answer (score 0):

The code in `$this->request->getVar('code')` will be generated only when you will hit the URL created using `$google_client->createAuthUrl();`

So, you can do it like this...

In Controller write
`$data['loginButton'] = $google_client->createAuthUrl();`

Pass this `$data['loginButton']` to the view in the anchor tag for the **Sign in with Google** button.

Now when you will click on the **Sign in with Google** button it will redirect back to the same `localhost.com/login` URL but this time you will have the **code** in the URL. So you can fetch it with `$this->request->getVar('code')` and follow the rest of the process.

- Please make sure all the detail like **ClientId** & **ClientSecret** is correct
- And update to the latest `"google/apiclient": "^2.10"`